# How can I specify the controller name and action name inside my own route handler?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm adding one new route to `RouteCollection` like this:

```
routes.Add(new Route("{*data}", new MyRoutehandler()));
```

How can I specify the controller name and action name inside this `MyRouteHandler` (my own route handler)?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here:

- [Custom routing for ASP.NET MVC](https://web.archive.org/web/20150529085244/http://codingcockerel.co.uk:80/2008/05/26/custom-routing-for-asp-net-mvc/)
- [ASP.Net MVC Framework - Create your own IRouteHandler](https://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/asp-net-mvc-framework-create-your-own-iroutehandler)
- [ASP.Net MVC Framework - Creating a IRouteHandler which will support Interceptors](https://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/asp-net-mvc-framework-creating-a-iroutehandler-which-will-support-interceptors)
- [ASP.NET MVC tips: Routing Engine to aid SEO / 301 Redirect / Tracking](https://web.archive.org/web/20210122073213/http://www.geekswithblogs.net/shahed/archive/2009/02/14/129386.aspx)

Comment: In all cases we are able to change the controller dynamically.
But I want to change both controller name as well as Action name..
please give me some guidence...

Comment: Try to implement custom ControllerFactory and set is as default in Application_Start